# Input addEventListener doesn't work on change

Tags: javascript, vue.js

please help me out in this. I am trying to save profile picture but the input.addeventlistener doesn't files on change. I am using vue with rails

This is the mount hook in when in a vue component where I want to trigger the eventlistener.

```
    mounted() {
    debugger
    this.previewUrl = this.placeholder;
    
    const input = this.$refs.inputSlot.querySelector('input[type="file"]')
    if (input) {
      input.addEventListener('change', event => {
        if(input.files[0]){
        const fakeFilePath  = event.currentTarget.value
        if (input.files[0].size > this.sizeLimit) {
          alert(this.$t('error.file_size', { max_size: this.maxSize }));
          input.value = '';
        } else {
          this.fileName = input.files[0].name

          if (this.preview == 'image') {
            const reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = event => {
              this.selectedFile = this.oldImage = this.previewUrl;
              this.previewUrl =  event.target.result;
              this.choosenFile = fakeFilePath;
            };
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
          }
        }
      }
      })
    }
  }
```

This is the input field

`<input accept="image/jpeg,image/png,.jpeg" type="file" name="user[profile_picture]" id="user_profile_picture">`

Comment: Are you sure it's finding the input? Put a console.log inside the `if` to be sure it's running.

Comment: ```if (input) ``` works but here the ```addEventListener('change``` doesn't work.

Comment: Could some later code be removing and recreating the input element?

Comment: If you put a console.log in the event listener, does it appear when you change the input?

Comment: @tony19 So basically I want to accept a file. On adding the file, the  ```input.addEventListner ``` doesn't work. @Barmar it prints the input element and it doesn't reflects the change.

Comment: @BurhanGardezi So are you saying the `change`-event isn't firing?

Comment: @tony19 Yes thats exactly what I am trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add @change="save" attribute to your input and after file change save method will gets triggered